# Evaluating $C_v$ for one mole of $H_2$ molecules in a quantum simulation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, simulations

Given an ensemble of $N$ diatomic molecules, we know that the rotational partition function is given by $$Z_r = z_r^N$$ where $$z_r = \sum_{l} (2l+1)e^{-Kl(l+1)}$$ where $K = \beta \hbar ^2 /2I$.

I want to apply this to calculate the $C_v$ for an ensemble of $H_2$ (hydrogen) molecules in the low $T$ limit and the high $T$ limit for a certain quantum mechanical simulation. Before I run the simulation, I want to have an idea of how the results should look like.

For a general canonical ensemble, $C_v = \left( \partial E / \partial T \right)_V$, where $E = -(\partial Z / \partial \beta$). *How would I evaluate the $C_v$ for a system of one mole of para-$H$ (singlet state) and one mole of ortho-$H$ (triplet state), and HD (D is deuterium) in the high temperature limit and low temperature limit?*

After looking at [this document](http://www.cmp.caltech.edu/%7Emcc/Ph127/a/Lecture_19.pdf) I can figure out the first 2 problems of evaluating $C_v$ for ortho and para $H_2$. How do I get the partition function for $HD$?

Comment: Using the rotational partition function alone is not likely to be sufficient. $C_v$ also contains contributions from both the translational motion of the molecules (which is dominant in the low-$T$ limit) and the vibrational modes (which are relevant in the high-$T$ limit).

Comment: Thanks for your input @probably_someone. if you check out the link i have attached, they have come up with $C_v$ values using the rotational and spin partition functions. How could I use that for HD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike the hydrogen or deuterium molecule, which are *homonuclear* diatomic molecules and hence are restricted by exchange symmetry considerations, HD is a *heteronuclear* diatomic molecule. Its components are distinguishable, which means that the exchange symmetry restrictions on possible rotational states goes away.

So, unlike the calculation of the rotational partition function for hydrogen or deuterium, which is complicated by the fact that only certain orbital $l$ are allowed for certain nuclear spin states $I$, in the heteronuclear case you simply use the ordinary rotational partition function of a linear rotor (in other words, the expression for $z_r$ that you've already written, where $l=0,1,2,...$). The vibrational and translational partition functions take the same form as in the homonuclear case.

Comment: So i can follow the same route to calculate $C_v$?